# Como detectar un error en SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Es una pregunta sin script pues mi duda es directa.

Yo necesito actualizar una Columna cuyo dato es X lo quiero convertir en Y pero cuando actualizo me da el siguiente error:

Error convertir Varchar a real.

por lo que se este error se da en algun trigger cuya variable esta declarada como varchar y en la tabla esta esta declarada como varchar. resulta que en mi tabla no poseo NINGUN TRIGGER y no se de donde me esta saliendo el error al actualizar. Mi pregunta es ¿Existe algun script que me ayude a revisar donde esta el error de declaracion de variables?

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes utilizar el log de errores de SQL Server desde el SQL Server Managment

Aqui se detalla como: [Registro de errores de SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)